# SQL query giving error mentioned below

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have one sql query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger_vacation_mode` AFTER UPDATE ON `oc_ms_seller`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if NEW.vacation_mode <> OLD.vacation_mode THEN

    UPDATE `oc_product` AS p
    SET p.date_modified = NOW()
    WHERE p.product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM `oc_ms_seller` AS ms join
    `oc_ms_product` AS mp ON ms.seller_id = mp.seller_id)

 END IF;
END;
```

I am getting this error when it is executed

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
END' at line 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the default delimiter (;)

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger_vacation_mode` AFTER UPDATE ON `oc_ms_seller`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if NEW.vacation_mode <> OLD.vacation_mode THEN

    UPDATE `oc_product` AS p
    SET p.date_modified = NOW()
    WHERE p.product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM `oc_ms_seller` AS ms join
    `oc_ms_product` AS mp ON ms.seller_id = mp.seller_id);

 END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The `DELIMITER` statement changes the standard delimiter which is semicolon ( `;`) to another ( here `//`).

Comment: getting error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;
END' at line 11

Comment: Try now there shouldnot be a semicolon after end

Answer (score 0):

Add a `;` to the end of your inner query `UPDATE...`.

You need to terminate the inner query inside the IF statement.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trigger_vacation_mode` AFTER UPDATE ON `oc_ms_seller`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        if NEW.vacation_mode <> OLD.vacation_mode THEN

            UPDATE `oc_product` AS p
            SET p.date_modified = NOW()
            WHERE p.product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM `oc_ms_seller` AS ms join
                `oc_ms_product` AS mp ON ms.seller_id = mp.seller_id);
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: still getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: Do you send the query inside the sql cli ?